# How to read a very messy .txt file using pd.read.csv() with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas

I have a very messy .txt file that I'm attempting to read in using pd.read_csv().  The file has multiple challenges to overcome 1) The first 12 lines are not needed and therefore need to be skipped, the next 50 rows are needed, the next 14 rows need to be Skipped, next 50 rows needed, next 14 to be skipped , and so on.    2) Each normal row of data actually exists across 2 rows of data in this report, meaning that we need to lift the 2nd row of data up to the 1st row of data and place it to the right in new columns. (This action would halve the number of total rows and double the number of columns of the desired dataframe)  3) The last challenge is that the first row of data has 8 spaces of seperation between values while the 2 row of data has anywhere from 8 through to 17 spaces of sep between values.

I thought the best way to approach this would be to first remove the rows that I don't need.  I would then find way to merge row 1 with row2 / row 3 with row 4/ row 5 with row 6 until all rows are correctly consolidated.  I would then use the 'sep' function to separate values of each row for anything that has 8 spaces and over.  This would hopefully get to my desired Output - has anyone ever had a similar challenge that they have overcome?

First picture is an image of the raw data [image]

Second picture is my ideal output[image]

Comment: most of you issues can be solved using attributes in ```.read_csv()``` like ```skiprows=```  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html, but before you use it you have to read it as a txt file and put every row in one row. ```read_csv``` will raise an error where a line has to many fields, you can turn it off using ```error_bad_lines=False``` but it will omit them

Comment: Thanks for the error_bad_lines=False tip.  I have loaded as txt and had to do a little reworking on the sep element to get it working but looks good.  will post code underneath

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the error_bad_lines=False combined with sep = '\s+|\^+'  worked a treat.

I then solved the problem of bad lines by removing them one by one.
I then solved the '1 row over 2 rows' problem by splitting the dataframe into two dfs (df8,df9) and recombined them on axis=1.  Looks perfect now.

```
import pandas as pd     #importing Pandas Package to wrangle data

boltcogs = 'ABAPlist.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(boltcogs,skiprows=12,error_bad_lines=False,header = None ,sep = '\s+|\^+')

df1 = df[df.iloc[:,0] != 'Production' ]  ## removing verbose lines
df2 = df1[df1.iloc[:,0] != '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' ]
df3 = df2[df2.iloc[:,0] != 'Kuala' ] ## removing bad rows
df4 = df3[df3.iloc[:,0] != 'Operating' ] ## removing bad rows
df5 = df4[df4.iloc[:,0] != 'Plant:' ] ## removing bad rows
df6 = df5[df5.iloc[:,0] != 'Costing' ] ## removing bad rows
df7 = df6[df6.iloc[:,0] != 'Currency:' ] ## removing bad rows

df8 = df7.iloc[0::2, :].reset_index() # Selecting every second row to get second half of row
df9 = df7.iloc[1::2, :].reset_index()# Selecting remainder to to get first half of row

df10 = pd.concat([df8, df9], axis=1, ignore_index=True) # joining them together
```